# is there any difference in mobile signal strength and data connection strength?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app which gives signal strength of various mobile networks ,
here is a few things I need to know
1 : I am getting phone signal strength like 13,14,17 using TelePhonyManager ,
what it actually means

2 : So if this declares the mobile signal strength , can the same strength be assumed for data being using using edge , 3G or any other way

i dont need full source codes ,
a little guidance should be sufficient.